# countable nouns and uncoutable nouns: water and an (the) apple(s)

Tags: grammar, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

"Bread and butter" can be plural and singular and it denpends on the context  but how about some combinations like countable and uncountable words? For example, "(a) water and an (the) apple(s)" ?

> Water and apples are (is) served.

If we take them as one thing,  it can be singular?
or it's just plural whatever the context would be ?

Comment: (Ignoring the fact that you can order “a water”?…)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You're right.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Context, you've just answered your own question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'll put more details. Thank you.

Comment: @AndyBonner Actually you _can_ order "a water" in the same sense that you can order "a beer" or "a coffee". However water, beer and coffee are rather more commonly used as non-count nouns and only measured quantities can be referred to using the indefinite article.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that complicated in the abstract.

1. Uncountable nouns are treated as singular ("some flour **goes** into the pie").
2. Countable nouns can be plural ("three apples **go** into the pie").
3. If you have a combination of countable and uncountable, congratulations, you have a compound subject, and ergo a plural ("three apples and some flour **go** into the pie").

Your first example, "bread and butter," is a compound noun. Although the word "and" is included, it's treated as one thing ("gin and tonic **is** the best drink" "'Twist and Shout' **is** an over-rated song"). When you use them together you mean a different thing than when you use them separately. "Gin and tonic are both liquids"—that sentence is no longer talking about the same thing as "gin and tonic." So it's an equivocation to say that "bread and butter" can be either singular or plural. The same words can be used in a singular compound noun, or as two unrelated nouns on their own.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate countable and/or uncountable nouns they take a **singular** verb if they are intended as a *combination* or are considered together as some kind of unit, be it food, things, actions, etc. Of course they take the usual plural when they are separate things. The nature of the nouns (countable or uncountable) really doesn't come into play.

---

> **Canned peas and carrots is** the product which has been properly prepared from clean, sound, succulent garden peas and clean, sound
> carrots. The peas and carrots **are** packed in a suitable packing
> medium with or without the addition of salt, sugar, or other
> ingredient(s) permissible under the Federal Food, Drug, and Cosmetic
> act;... [*Federal Register*, Vol. 35](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Federal_Register/-FljIhx2nFoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22peas%20and%20carrots%20is%22&pg=PA2788&printsec=frontcover) p. 2788

Peas and carrots is (**singular**) one canned product, but to make the product, the ingredients (peas and carrots) are (**plural**) first packed in a medium.

> The **lox, eggs, and onions is good** if you tell them to make sure
> the onions are well-cooked. [Transcript from *The Reliable Source*,
> Aug. 23, 2002](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/liveonline/source/source082302.htm)
> [uncountable + countable + countable]

> ... to contradict Marcella Hazan, who states firmly in her equally
> estimable *Classic Italian Cook Book*, "**Rice and peas is** not a
> risotto with peas. It is a soup." [John Thorne; *Simple Cooking*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Simple_Cooking/VEWmQ53--v0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rice%20and%20peas%20is%22&pg=PR25&printsec=frontcover)

> **Rice and beans is** a classic combination. Each Latino group has a
> favorite bean for it and some even have distinctive whimsical names.
> [Zilkia Janer; *Latino Food Culture*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Latino_Food_Culture/KxYTgVXvc3oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rice%20and%20beans%20is%22&pg=PA30&printsec=frontcover)

> **Fox and hounds is** a race. We start off at opposite corners of the house. [David Mitchell; *Slade House*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Slade_House/v2wlBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fox%20and%20hounds%20is%22&pg=PT17&printsec=frontcover)

> Father – who believed that **bricks and mortar was** a solid base for
> financial security – had already invested in holiday flats in Spain at
> Bela Medina and Marbella when an opportunity was offered for ...
> [Graham Wren; *A Rugy and a Rose Came to Derby*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Ruby_and_a_Rose_Came_to_Derby/7sMkEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bricks%20and%20mortar%20was%22&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover)

> **Catch and release works** to maintain healthy populations of fish and there must be enough fish in any given area to maintain or grow
> the population. ["Catch and Release vs. Catch and Keep Fishing"](https://blog.vailvalleyanglers.com/catch-and-release-vs-catch-and-keep-fishing-part-1/)